# UWP C# FolderPicker without Dialog

Tags: c#, uwp, directory, storage

I have the following Code

```
var picker = new FolderPicker();
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*"); 
            var pfolder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(pfolder);
            StorageFile file = await pfolder.GetFileAsync("Kundenliste.xml");
```

it is possible to give the `FolderPicker` a fixed Folder? The Dialog from `FolderPicker` should not pop-up, but I need to access the Folder C:\.

It is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP apps run in a sandbox, so that the user can install them in a safe manner and doesn't have to worry about the app accessing a folder she didn't give it access to.

In this case, if you need to access the C: drive, there are two solutions depending on the version of Windows 10 you target.

If you target Fall Creators Update (1709 - 16299) or lower, you must use the `FolderPicker` dialog to ask the user to pick the folder manually.

If you target the Spring Creators Update (1803 - probably 17110), you can declare the new [`broadFileSystemAccess` capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations), which will enable your app to access any location the user has access to, but there must be a reason why your app would need such a thing, because it is evaluated during the certification process on the Microsoft Store.

In addition, if your app declares an [app execution alias](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/07/05/command-line-activation-universal-windows-apps/#QAsPT3MMX8EfLJgg.97), it automatically gets rights to access the filesystem tree from the folder where it is launched from downwards. You don't need any special permissions for this.

Comment: so i cant prevent the Dialog ?

Comment: No, the dialog cannot be prevented, because that would defeat the goal of letting the user know your app needs to access some folder that he actually did not allow. Before Spring Creators Update, the picker was the only solution. From Spring Creators Update the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability is the alternative.

Comment: Thank you! Your the best :)

Comment: Glad to help :-) . Happy coding!

Comment: Hi again. I have now (like everyone) the Spring Update. But how can i target my App to this Update. The latest Version i get is still Fall Creators.

Comment: You have to download the Spring Update SDK. It should be available on dev.windows.com :-)